How do I get the phone number and extension on this phone number using regex
I have phone numbers in the format below, the first numbers followed by a "-"(dash) is the country code and the last numbers after the "x" is the extension. Anything in between is the  phone number, I want to capture the phone number and extension.
1-1231312x24 //phone: 1231312, extension: 24
21-1231312x24 //phone: 1231312, extension: 24
1-343454 //phone: 343454 
1-2-3545645x243 //phone: 2-3545645, extension :243
4343444x25 //phone: 4343444, extension: 25 
454545545 //phone: 454545545

I'm trying the regex (\d*-?)(\d+)x?(\d*), this worked for my first 3 examples but not the rest.

Maybe ((?:\d+-)*\d+)(?:x(\d+))?

You do not allow the dash in your phone-number part, how about ^(\d+-)?([\d-]+)x?(\d*) (note that [\d-]+ is not very accurate for the number, it would even match ---). Do you actually need to capture the country-code? Further, are you matching full strings like your samples and it can be anchored to ^ start or extract from some larger text?

Or something along ((?:(?<=\d-)\d+-)*\d+)(?:x(\d+))?(?![\d-]) https://regex101.com/r/emIFSA/1

Thank you @bobblebubble, this regex worked and I don't mind the other characters as long as I remove the first "X-" at the beginning. Feel free to post as answer

If the phone number part can contain dashes - and the country code is optional: how do you want to detect when a phone number doesn't start with a country code but still has one or more dashes in it?

Your current regex does not match a dash in the second group (\d+) (phone-number part). To also match hyphens between digits in that part you can use [\d-]+ or more concise \d+(?:-\d+)*.
^(\d+-)?(\d+(?:-\d+)*)x?(\d*)

See this demo at regex101  (anchored to ^ start)
I further changed your first group (\d*-?) to (\d+-)? to prevent consuming digits without hyphen.
